# What's the difference between dtype and converters in pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, types, converters, type-inference

pandas function read_csv() reads a .csv file. Its documentation is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

According to documentation, we know:

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None Data type
>   for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32}
>   (Unsupported with engine=’python’)

and

> converters : dict, default None Dict of functions for converting
>   values in certain columns. Keys can either be integers or column
>   labels

When using this function, I can call either
`pandas.read_csv('file',dtype=object)` or `pandas.read_csv('file',converters=object)`. Obviously, converter, its name can says that data type will be converted but I wonder the case of dtype?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The semantic difference is that `dtype` allows you to specify how to treat the values, for example, either as numeric or string type.

Converters allows you to parse your input data to convert it to a desired dtype using a conversion function, e.g, parsing a string value to datetime or to some other desired dtype.

Here we see that pandas tries to sniff the types:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
t="""int,float,date,str
001,3.31,2015/01/01,005"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
int      1 non-null int64
float    1 non-null float64
date     1 non-null object
str      1 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 40.0+ bytes
```

You can see from the above that `001` and `005` are treated as `int64` but the date string stays as `str`.

If we say everything is `object` then essentially everything is `str`:

```
In [3]:    
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype=object).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
int      1 non-null object
float    1 non-null object
date     1 non-null object
str      1 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 40.0+ bytes
```

Here we force the `int` column to `str` and tell `parse_dates` to use the date_parser to parse the date column:

```
In [6]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), dtype={'int':'object'}, parse_dates=['date']).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
int      1 non-null object
float    1 non-null float64
date     1 non-null datetime64[ns]
str      1 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 40.0+ bytes
```

Similarly we could've pass the `to_datetime` function to convert the dates:

```
In [5]:
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), converters={'date':pd.to_datetime}).info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
int      1 non-null int64
float    1 non-null float64
date     1 non-null datetime64[ns]
str      1 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 40.0 bytes
```

Comment: I should point out for others that both parameters can be provided in the same `read_csv` invocation, although I haven't tested for overlapping columns referenced in both `dtypes` and the `converters` dictionaries if using that API.

Comment: Is there a way to make your own sniffer that converts dtypes? I feel this would be useful with excel files with many columns.

Comment: That won't work excel sheets are imported using a 3rd party module so the dtypes are provided via that module. If it was a csv file then you could define your own function and load this to converter and have this applied on every column, that would work

Comment: In reply to @jxramos comment, ``converters`` takes precedence over ``dtypes`` in case the same column is referenced in both arguments, at least on pandas 1.3.1

Answer (score 8):

I would say that the main purpose for `converters` is to manipulate the values of the column, not the datatype. The answer shared by @EdChum focuses on the idea of the `dtypes`. It uses the `pd.to_datetime` function.

Within this article https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/make-the-most-out-of-your-pandas-read-csv-1531c71893b5 in the area about **converters**, you will see an example of changing a csv column, with values such as "185 lbs.", into something that removes the "lbs" from the text column. This is more of the idea behind the `read_csv` `converters` parameter.

*What the .csv looks like* (If the image doesn't show up, please go to the article.)
[image: the csv file with 6 columns. Weight is column with entries like 145 lbs.]

```
#creating functions to clean the columns
w = lambda x: (x.replace('lbs.',''))
r = lambda x: (x.replace('"',''))
#using converters to apply the functions to the columns
fighter = pd.read_csv('raw_fighter_details.csv' , 
                      converters={'Weight':w , 'Reach':r }, 
                      header=0, 
                      usecols = [0,1,2,3])
fighter.head(15)
```

*The `DataFrame` after using `converters` on the Weight column.*
[image]

Comment: Note that the `r` lambda function was used on the `Reach` column, and not on the Height column.

Answer (score 0):

We use Converters to change the value of a perticular cell

We can write a function for a particular column inside the Converters and it will run for every cell in that column .

Please see the below example , this is a dataframe and we are trying to change those highlight values

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz5RG.png)

```
   import pandas as pd
def converst_peopple_cell(cell):
  if cell=='n.a.':
    return 'Sam Walton'
  else:
    return cell       # if the cell value is not 'n.a.' then it will return the orginal value of the cell
def convert_eps_cell(cell):
  if cell=='not available':
    return None
  else:
    return cell
df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebasics/py/master/pandas/4_read_write_to_excel/stock_data.csv',converters={
    'people': converst_peopple_cell,
    'eps':convert_eps_cell
   
})
df
```

We use Converters arguments , which is like a python dictionary ,we can select some particular column and can apply some particular function, for a particular column like people it is gonna call this funtion convert_people_cell for every single cell in that column .
The DataFrame after using converters on the people column

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A0Sc.png)