# pandas.Dataframe equivalent for Pandas.read_csv converters?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139102/whats-the-difference-between-dtype-and-converters-in-pandas-read-csv) covers the differences between `dtypes`and `converters` in `pandas.read_csv` function.

I could not find an equivalent to converters for the pandas.DataFrame constructor in the documentation.

If I build a dataframe directly from a list of lists, what would be the best way to mimic the same behavior?

Some made-up example:

```
# data.csv

sport,population
football,15M
darts,50k
sailing,3000
```

```
# convert_csv_to_df.py

import pandas as pd

def f_population_to_int(population):
    dict_multiplier={"k": 1000, "M": 1000000}
    try:
         multiplier = dict_multiplier[population[-1]]
         return int(population[0:-1]) * multiplier
    except KeyError:
         return population

dict_converters = {"population": f_population_to_int}
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", converters=dict_converters)
```

output:

```
      sport population 
0  football   15000000 
1     darts      50000 
2   sailing       3000
```

What would be the best way to get the same dataframe from a list of lists?

```
data = [["sports", "population"], ["football", "15M"], ["darts", "50k"], ["sailing", 3000]]
```

### Edit for clarification:

The example dict_converter holds only one function, but the idea is to be able to apply different conversions for multiple columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `f_population_to_int` function for return same value if any error (remove `KeyError`) and after create DataFrame use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
data = [["sports", "population"], ["football", "15M"], ["darts", "50k"], ["sailing", 3000]]


def f_population_to_int(population):
    dict_multiplier={"k": 1000, "M": 1000000}
    try:
         multiplier = dict_multiplier[population[-1]]
         return int(population[0:-1]) * multiplier
    except:
         return population

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
df['population'] = df['population'].apply(f_population_to_int)

print (df)
     sports population
0  football   15000000
1     darts      50000
2   sailing       3000
```

If need dict `dict_converters` use:

```
dict_converters = {"population": f_population_to_int}
for k, v in dict_converters.items():
    df[k] = df[k].apply(v)
```

Comment: thanks, I wanted to avoid bare except but I guess this is a good case for making an exception. In my case, I have a dict_converter of {"column": function}. I guess I would have to iterate over it, to apply each function then?

Comment: @jazzfan - Added to answer.